# Rings in which binomial theorem holds for at least one integer $n>2$

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, binomial-theorem

Let $R$ be a ring ; if $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2 , \forall a,b \in R$ , then we know that $R$ is commutative ; also if $R$ is commutative then we know that $(a+b)^n=\sum _{r=0}^n {n \choose r} a^{n-r}b^r , \forall a,b \in R , \forall n \in \mathbb Z^+ $ ; so I would like to ask , under what additional conditions on $R$ , does for a fixed given $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ , $(a+b)^n=\sum _{r=0}^n {n \choose r} a^{n-r}b^r , \forall a,b \in R$ implies $R$ is commutative ? what if we also include the condition for some positive integer (or all ) $m>1$ ,  $(ab)^m=a^mb^m , \forall a,b \in R$ ?

Is it true that for every integer $n>2$ , there exist a non-commutative ring $R$ such that $(a+b)^n=\sum _{r=0}^n {n \choose r} a^{n-r}b^r , \forall a,b \in R$?

Comment: Actually, I think I have seen something along the lines of the $(ab)^m=a^mb^m$ conjecture... I'll have to look into finding it...

Answer (score 9):

Let $R$ be the ring of $3\times3$ real matrices of the form 
$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ x&0&0 \\ y&z&0\end{bmatrix}$.

This ring is not commutative; for example 
$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$
and
$\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ do not commute.

Every triple product is $0$, so, for $n\ge3$, the binomial theorem reduces to $0=0$.

Comment: I like this example since it very clearly generalizes to all $n > 3$. This suggests that one of the conditions one might need to impose is that the elements in the ring are non-nilpotent in order to get commutativity, though I'm not sure how far that line of thought can get you.

Comment: And, if you like your rings to have $1$, you can modify this example by imposing that the diagonal elements all be equal, rather than all be $0$.

Comment: David, I have some doubts. If the ring has unity and the binomial theorem holds true for $n=3$, then the expansion of $\big(1+(a+b)\big)^3-(a+b)^3$ yields $3(ab-ba)=0$.

Comment: (Hope I did not miss it.. :-) )

Comment: @user141614 Can you elaborate a bit on the algebra in your comment?  I'm not sure which you are expanding out and which you are applying the binomial theorem to.  I can't get 3(ab - ba) = 0 like you did.

Comment: OK, I try it. I arranged $(1+a+b)^3-(a+b)^3$ in two different ways. May be it is simpler to do it in this way: \begin{align*}
  0 &= \big(1+(a+b)\big)^3 - \big((1+a)+b\big)^3 \\
  &= \big(1+3(a+b)+3(a+b)^2+(a+b)^3\big) -
  \big((1+a)^3+3(1+a)^2b+3(1+a)b^2+b^3\big) \\
  &= \big(1+3(a+b)+3(a^2+ab+ba+b^2)+(a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3)\big) \\
  & ~~~- \big((1+3a+3a^2+a^3) + 3(1+2a+a^2)b+3(1+a)b^2+b^3 \big) \\
  &= 3(ba-ab).
\end{align*}